# Closed Objects in Adobe illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

[image: image for Question]

I am new to Adobe illustrator. There are 13 Paths available in the above Picture. My Question here is to can we make the above Paths into three closed Paths. As joining mentioned below

Path one 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 Path two 8 , 5 , 6 ,7,10 ,9 Path three 9 , 12 , 13 , 11

How can we do that in Adobe illustrator. Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such thing as "joining" or "connecting" a path to the *middle* of another path. It's simply not possible in Illustrator. Simply **overlap** one side of each shape (i.e. 5 and 9) and the overlap will *appear* to be a single path.

Comment: Sure use shapebuilder, the inner edges will be duplicated. But then your model is not the printers model.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make 3 separate paths then use shapebuilder.

However, illustrator can not make nonmanifold structures. (aka t crossings). It does not need to. Vector drawing is in a sense converting your mental model into the drawing model of the vector format. Sometimes this means needing to have several copies of parts of your mental model.

There are a lot of things that such a format could implement. But they implement only functionality thats strictly neccesery for drawing tasks. There is no need to implement a t crossing. Two stroked curves can overlap and that looks like a t crossing even if its not, and a fill never needs to be nonmanifold.